# Real Analysis: Is Intersection of I_n Compact?

Tags: real-analysis

For each $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define $I_n = (1 - \frac{1}{n}, 3 - \frac{1}{n}]$.

Is ${\bigcap}_{n=1}^∞ I_n$  compact?

Solution Attempt:

Let $a_n = 1 - \frac{1}{n} $ and $b_n = 3 - \frac{1}{n}$

Since $\lim_{n→∞} a_n = 1$ and $\lim_{n→∞} b_n = 3$. We have $\lim_{n→∞} I_n = (1,3)$

Since $b_n = 2 \in I_n$ for all $n \implies b_n \in I_n$

Consider ${\bigcap}_{n=1}^∞ (a_n,b_n] =(1,2]$

Note that ${\bigcap}_{n=1}^∞ (a_n,b_n] =(1,2]$ is not compact since $1$ is a limit point of $I$ but $ 1 \notin I$ thus $I$ is not closed and hence $I$ is not compact.

Comment: Isn't $1>1-1/n$ for each $n=1,2,\ldots$, so $1\in(a_n,b_n]$ for all $n$?

Comment: $1$ is in the intersection (the interval is $[1,2]$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That intersection is exactly the closed interval [1,2]. In fact $3-\frac{1}{n}$ is an increasing sequence, so clearly the interval that you get will be something like $(a,2]$ or $[a,2]$, for some $a$. Now, also the sequence $1-\frac{1}{n}$ is increasing and its limit is $1$. From this you get that for every number $b$ smaller than $1$, exists a natural $n$ such that $1-\frac{1}{n} > b$, so every number smaller than $1$ is not in the intersection. Finally, $1$ is in $I_n$ for every $n$, and so are the number between $1$ and $2$. So the answer would be yes, because the intersection is the interval $[1,2]$, and it's compact because it's closed and bounded.

Comment: thanks but can you please write all the steps.